# Synonymize [web3] to [web3js]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The [web3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3) tag was created in the height of the crypto craze (web "3.0"), but was intended for use with just the JS library [web3js](https://web3js.org/), a library for working with Ethereum, a specific crypto currency.

However, over time many other versions of this library have come out for different languages (e.g. for Java, for Python, for Rust, for PHP, and many more). These libraries, including the original web3js, all have their own specific tags now, which is great.

Unfortunately, people are regularly still using [web3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3), out of laziness and/or ignorance, for any question about any web3 library. Also unfortunately, the tag cleanup bug that has been plaguing various tags for several years now also applies to [web3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3) (this is the bug that causes tag removal/wiki deletion to fail overnight when there are zero undeleted questions remaining). The impact of this is that these people asking new questions aren't caught by the 1500-rep gate of 'are you sure you want to create a new tag?' which would otherwise probably prevent 95% or more of these new questions from using that tag.

I update the tags on several new questions a day to try and apply the correct language-specific library tag to new questions that come in, but it would be great if this weren't needed anymore.

To solve this, can we please have a moderator mark [web3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3) as a synonym of [web3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3js) so that it stops getting used by people who mean something else (or at least, gets used far less frequently)?

Comment: I renamed it to [[tag:web3-donotuse]] (which, despite a search returning no questions, nonetheless claims to have updated 3 rows...).  Do you think that's sufficient?  If I were creating a synonym, I'd probably go with [[tag:blockchain]], as that's the closest thing to my understanding of the meaning of the (somewhat poorly defined, IMO) term "web3".

Comment: @RyanM Actually, yeah synonymizing web3 to blockchain is probably a good idea afterward since the term 'web3' itself refers to web 3.0 which is basically just 'blockchain' hype.

Comment: As someone not in the know, can [web3] be suitable as a language-agnostic tag? Or the concept of "what is web3" just too nebulous to have SMEs and its just better to have specific tags for libraries that do web3-ish stuff?

Comment: @kmdreko It's too nebulous. The term 'web 3.0' was a buzzword co-opted by cryptocurrency pushers to suggest that we were entering a new 'paradigm' of interacting with the web (like how 'web 2.0' introduced user-authoring of content on a broad scale back in the aughts), but that was largely overblown and not really an accurate portrayal. There is no value in having a language-agnostic [web3] tag even to refer to a library by the name of web3 in a given language, as some other languages may create web3 libraries totally unrelated to cryptocurrency.

Comment: @kmdreko Given that most questions that use such tags also tend to include tags like [<language>] [ethereum] [smartcontracts], that only leaves one space for an additional _relevant_ tag. ethereum or blockchain or smartcontracts tags already cover the topic that a generic [web3] tag would, also.

Comment: Is it better to have a [web3] -> [blockchain] synonym, or just nothing about web3 at all?

Comment: @RyanM In my opinion, the latter... but to be reasonable, it's probably better to synonymize it so people don't recreate it.

Comment: @RyanM web3 is not really the same as blockchain, I wouldn't synonymize it. It might be a good idea to blacklist it though…

Comment: @Bergi, I disagree, web 3.0 is literally the callsign for blockchain and blockchain-related "decentralization" services (which invariably end up being centralized anyway).